# Not able to delete items from Outlook Deleted Items folder

Tags: c#, outlook

I am using Outlook from Office 365 and this is the code in C# I have to delete the items in the "Deleted items" folder.

It gives an error when I do this conversion:

```
var idList = (from MailItem item in binFolder.Items select item.EntryID).ToList();
```

This is the complete code:

```
public void DeleteBin()
{
    ApplicationClass outlookApp = new ApplicationClass();
    var binFolder = outlookApp.Session
                              .GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
    var idList = (from MailItem item in binFolder.Items select item.EntryID).ToList();
    DeleteFromId(idList);
}

// It gets a list of emails ID and remove it from the outlook
private void DeleteFromId(List<string> idList)
{
    foreach (var id in idList)
    {
        var item = (MailItem)mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(id);
        item.Delete();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe you have to provide `binFolder.StoreID` as a second parameter to `mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID`, otherwise this call may and probably will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error occurs in the line

```
var idList = (from MailItem item in binFolder.Items select item.EntryID).ToList();
```

it can have several causes:

1. Not all items in the folder are of type `MailItem`.
2. There might be an exception thrown when accessing the `EntryID` property.

You can prevent/handle these kinds of problems by converting your Linq statement as follows:

```
var idList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in binFolder.Items.OfType<MailItem>())
{
    try
    {
        idList.Add(item.EntryID);
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

This fixes the error in your code, but it's very likely that the following will run much faster because you don't have to retrieve each item again:

```
var itemsToDelete = binFolder.Items.OfType<dynamic>().ToList();
foreach (var item in itemsToDelete)
{
    try
    {
        item.Delete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcosF8: If you find an answer helpful on Stack Overflow, please upvote. Thanks.